# How to show empty data in group by age in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two table, table mspencaker and mspengalaman. I make a query which displays the number of users based on age and gender range. so far the query has run smoothly, but when I change the date of the query, the results of the query will be empty. how to display all existing data from the database even though the data is empty, or replace the null data to 0.

this is my table

```
mspencaker
----------------
+ IDPencaker   +  --> ID OF table mspencaker(Primary key)
+ TglLahir     +  --> Date of birth from user
+ JenisKelamin +  --> gender of user
+ RegisterDate +  --> the date of registration user, and i use this field to 
----------------      filter data

mspengalaman
-------------------
+ IDpengalaman    +  --> ID OF table mspengalaman(Primary key)
+ IDPencaker      +  --> FOREIGN KEY of mspencaker
+ StatusPekerjaan +  --> i use this field to filter data
-------------------
```

This is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(p.IDPencaker, 0)) as total, 
CASE 
 WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) <= 14 THEN '0-14'
 WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN '15-19' 
 WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-29' 
 WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN '30-44' 
 WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 45 AND 54 THEN '45-54' 
 WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) >= 55 THEN '55' 
END AS age, 
SUM(COALESCE(p.JenisKelamin = 0, 0)) as laki, 
SUM(COALESCE(p.JenisKelamin = 1, 0) ) as cewe 
   FROM mspencaker p LEFT JOIN mspengalaman g 
   ON g.IDPencaker = p.IDPencaker AND g.StatusPekerjaan = 0 
   WHERE p.RegisterDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-07-01' 
   GROUP BY age
```

The result of query like this:

```
    age   | laki | cewe   | Total
----------+------+--------+------
    0-14  |  3   |   4    |  7
   15-19  |  2   |   1    |  3
   20-29  |  1   |   3    |  4
   30-44  |  10  |   1    |  11
   45-54  |  4   |   6    |  10
    55    |  2   |   1    |  3
```

BUT if i change `WHERE p.RegisterDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-07-01'` to `WHERE p.RegisterDate BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-07-01'`,then the result like this :

```
    age   | laki | cewe   | Total
----------+------+--------+------
   null   | null | null   |  null
```

I want if I change the condition then all data still appears and is given a value of 0 not given a null value.

Comment: I think your question is a bit confused. As a valid result, do you want a row with 0 (zero) in all columns or do you want simply ignore the filter `Register Date` and return all table rows?

Comment: forgive me for making you confused. I want if ```p.RegisterDate``` is changed and data from that date is not found then the entire age range appears with the contents of data 0

Comment: Check this script actually returns any data or not - SELECT * FROM mspencaker p WHERE p.RegisterDate BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-07-01'

Comment: "all data still appears" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Also give an example. When giving (base or query result) relation(ship)s/associations or tables say what a row says about the business situation in terms of its column values when it is in the table. PS Clarify via edits, not comments. PS Is there always supposed to be a row for every age range? If so, you can't get them by selecting from that data.

Comment: Seriously consider handling (all) issues of data display in application code

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM mspencaker p WHERE p.RegisterDate BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND '2019-07-01'``` not show any data, because no user registers on that date @mkRabbani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since not all age ranges appear every time in your result one solution would be to create another result set containing only the age ranges(all of them),`LEFT JOIN` it with the result set that contains your actual data and using `IFNULL()` to show 0 instead of NULL for the empty fields.

```
                SELECT t1.age,IFNULL(t2.laki,0) as laki,IFNULL(t2.cewe,0) as cewe,IFNULL(t2.Total, 0) AS Total  FROM
                (
                SELECT '0-14' AS age
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT '15-19' AS age
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '20-29' AS age
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '30-44' AS age 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '45-54' AS age  
                UNION ALL
                SELECT '55' AS age 
                ) t1 
                LEFT JOIN 
                (
                SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(p.IDPencaker, 0)) as total, 
                CASE 
                WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) <= 14 THEN '0-14'
                WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN '15-19' 
                WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-29' 
                WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN '30-44' 
                WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 45 AND 54 THEN '45-54' 
                WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.TglLahir, CURDATE()) >= 55 THEN '55' 
                END AS age, 
                SUM(COALESCE(p.JenisKelamin = 0, 0)) as laki, 
                SUM(COALESCE(p.JenisKelamin = 1, 0) ) as cewe 
                FROM mspencaker p LEFT JOIN mspengalaman g 
                ON g.IDPencaker = p.IDPencaker AND g.StatusPekerjaan = 0 
                WHERE p.RegisterDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-07-01' 
                GROUP BY age
                )  t2 
                ON t1.age=t2.age
```

Comment: Explaining why you need the left join and base set (t1) would improve this answer.

Comment: thank you very much sir, this query worked for me^^